# Converting Java class to List<List<String>> to show in a table

Tags: java, list, lambda, hashmap, set

I would like to make a conversion between some classes in Java to be showed in a table.
I receive a `List<Version>` (Removed the getter/setter to make it shorter):

```
public class Version {
    private String server;
    private List<Job> jobs;
}
public class Job {
    private String name;
    private String version;
}
```

Now, what I do have is a tool to check the data of the servers for all the jobs:
 - Each item of the list is the information of one server, so multiple servers contains multiple jobs, but each of the servers have the same jobs, but the version can be different.
 - So, `Version.server` is the name of the server, `Job.name` the name of the job, and `Job.version` is the version of the job.
- Also, all the servers starts with the same name, for example: dev-1.lan, dev-2.lan, uk-1.lan, us-1.lan and etc;

Thanks to @Korolar, here is a valid input:

```
   var input = List.of(
            new Version("dev-1.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.1")
            )),
            new Version("dev-2.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.1")
            )),
            new Version("dev-3.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-1.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.0"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-2.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.0"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-3.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.0"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-4.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            ))
        );
```

I want to convert it to a table, to be easier to read. Where, I want to merge the jobs that contains the same name and version and, when a version is not the same, add one more line and indicate which server is not with the same version, E.g.:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| job        | DEV          | UK         |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| a          | 1.1.1        | 1.1.1      |
| b          | 10.0.1       | 10.0.0     |
| b          |              | 10.0.1 (4) |
| c          | 2.0.1        | 2.0.2      |
| c          | 2.0.1 (3)    |            |
+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Ok, so, as you can see, (x) is the server that is not right, for example, I received a `List<Version>` of at least 7 items (3 from DEV and 4 from UK), with exactly 3 jobs in each item of the list (`a`,`b` and `c`) and finally, for `a` I would have version 1.1.1 in all the 7 entries for the job `a`, while that for `b` I would have all 3 versions 10.0.1 in DEV but 3 versions 10.0.0 and 1 version 10.0.1, which is in server uk-4.lan in UK. Similar results would be the case for `c` as well, but the server with different results would be the dev-3.lan server.

Now, my question would be how can I transform the `List<Version>` in a simple `List<List<String>>` to represent this table or something similar? Don't worry about the print, because I already did this part.

So, I would expect my output to be something like:

```
var expectedOutput = List.Of
        List.of("apps","DEV", "Uk"),
        List.of("a", "1.1.1", "1.1.1"),
        List.of("b", "10.0.1", "10.0.0"),
        List.of("b", "", "10.0.1 (4)"),
        List.of("c", "2.0.1", "2.0.2"),
        List.of("c", "2.0.2 (3)", ""),
        )
    );
```

But, if you show me how I can generate a table using another type of structure it's also valid.

Many thanks,
Joao

Comment: Your question is not clear for us to answer. Please explain the input and desired output.

Comment: I believe that @korolar have a nice example of input, while that the output would be a variable Map<Integer, List<Strring>> where which integer would represent the line of the table and the List<String> would be the columns values. In the end I would like to see a table, doesn't need to be a Map, can be something else. Cheers, Joao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is not entirely clear around the "which server is not the same" issue. I don't think it's well defined. For example what if you have four servers, each with different job version?

With that in mind I've assumed that what you wanted is for the following test to pass:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class QuestionTest {
    @Test
    void example() {
        var input = List.of(
            new Version("dev-1.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.1")
            )),
            new Version("dev-2.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.1")
            )),
            new Version("dev-3.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-1.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.0"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-2.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.0"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-3.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.0"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            )),
            new Version("uk-4.lan", List.of(
                new Job("a", "1.1.1"),
                new Job("b", "10.0.1"),
                new Job("c", "2.0.2")
            ))
        );

        var expectedOutput = Map.of(
            "a", Map.of(
                "DEV", Map.of(
                    "1.1.1", Set.of(1, 2, 3)
                ),
                "UK", Map.of(
                    "1.1.1", Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
                )
            ),
            "b", Map.of(
                "DEV", Map.of(
                    "10.0.1", Set.of(1, 2, 3)
                ),
                "UK", Map.of(
                    "10.0.0", Set.of(1, 2, 3),
                    "10.0.1", Set.of(4)
                )
            ),
            "c", Map.of(
                "DEV", Map.of(
                    "2.0.1", Set.of(1, 2),
                    "2.0.2", Set.of(3)
                ),
                "UK", Map.of(
                    "2.0.2", Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
                )
            )
        );

        var actualOutput = Main.parse(input);

        assertEquals(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
    }
}
```

With this assumption your question is reduced to a fun exercise in using Java lambdas. The solution I've found is:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class Main {
    static Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Set<Integer>>>> parse(List<Version> input) {
        return input.stream()
            .flatMap(version -> version.jobs.stream().map(job -> new Entry(version, job)))
            .collect(
                groupingBy(
                    entry -> entry.jobName,
                    groupingBy(
                        entry -> entry.serverName,
                        groupingBy(
                            entry -> entry.jobVersion,
                            mapping(entry -> entry.serverNumber, toSet())
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

with helper class `Entry` defined as:

```
class Entry {
    final String serverName;
    final int serverNumber;
    final String jobName;
    final String jobVersion;

    Entry(Version version, Job job) {
        this.serverName = version.serverName;
        this.serverNumber = version.serverNumber;
        this.jobName = job.name;
        this.jobVersion = job.version;
    }
}
```

and with:

```
class Job {
    final String name;
    final String version;

    Job(String name, String version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Version {
    private static final Pattern SERVER_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)-(\\d+)\\.lan");

    final String server;
    final List<Job> jobs;

    final String serverName;
    final int serverNumber;

    Version(String server, List<Job> jobs) {
        this.server = server;
        this.jobs = List.copyOf(jobs);

        Matcher matcher = SERVER_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(server);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            this.serverName = matcher.group(1).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
            this.serverNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid server: " + server);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. 
When I said: `Each item of the list is the information of one server, so multiple servers contains multiple jobs, but each of the servers have the same jobs, but the version can be different.` I mean that I will always have the same jobs coming, but from different servers. Thanks for your example, it's appears to be a nice solution, let me test it and I will make it as the corrected one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your output of the parser: ` Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Set<Integer>>>>` How can I transform this in a table as showed in my question?

Comment: Ok, I used your solution in the end. What I changed was the way to show it, so now I'm showing it in the way that you are returning and is fine for now. Thanks.